# Youtube embeded in delphi autoplay&loop refreshing

Tags: delphi, youtube, autoplay

I've just made simple YouTube player in SDI using embedded links inside the `TWebBrowser` component, and managed to create auto play and loop (loop one and loop all) buttons as well as quality changing radio buttons, but they're all based on hyperlink changes, and therefore does not perform a change while video playing, but have to send "Go" command again. I've implemented it with the buttons mentioned above, but it's annoying to restart video when making a change, especially if I just want to set loop somewhere in the middle of the song.

Is there any way of maybe reading current time and set then set link with that time starting, or any other way of solving this, so when pressing the button, the action will be accepted with no refresh, or won't restart the video from beginning?

The default buttons for changing quality within the player itself does exactly that, but can't find a command.

Also, on YouTube there is a button in playlist to loop, as well as randomize, but can't find them either.

Comment: Are you using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#embedded_player)?

Comment: No. Simply TWebBrowser with the url link of http://youtube.com/v/ for embedded visual instead of whole site.
Thanks for reply!

Comment: Well, then you must consider use this API instead.